# BI Publisher in Word buttons don't work

Tags: bi-publisher

I've imported XML file and buttons in Word became available, but when I press neither works.

```
Code isn't important here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. My Word application wasn't registered. Now when registered everithing works.